# Write string to xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I save all attachments from an email:

```
List<Pop3Content> contentList = Pop3Message.GetAttachedContents(client.GetMessage(i).Contents, c => c.IsAttachment == true);

XmlDocument xml=new XmlDocument();

xml.LoadXml(contentList[0].BodyText);
```

this

```
contentList[0].BodyText
```

Returns the whole Content of an attached XML file, the way I want to have it in my  XmlDocument XML
But the method LoadXML expects a path to an actual XML file. How can I write strings into an "internal" XML file?

Comment: your assertion is wrong. `LoadXml` accepts a string representing an xml document, you are talking about `XDocument.Load`.

Comment: @Jodrell xml.Load(contentList[0].BodyText); not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method accepts string.

You can do

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<item><name>wrench</name></item>");
```

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx)

I think you need to do this

```
xml.LoadXml(contentList[0].BodyText.ToString());
```

Comment: still, it does not accept "contentList[0].BodyText", and I have to do it dynamically

Comment: @user2336688, that rather depends on what `contentList[0].BodyText` contains.

Comment: @user2336688: What type is `BodyText`? and how do you know that it does not allow you. if it raise some runtime/compile time exception. what exception?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item><name>wrench</name></item>

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, BodyText is a string with the Content Ive just posted

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal no, if i print out  contentList[0].BodyText, it has exactly the Content I wanna write in my XML file

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal tahnks for your patientce. it would work the way I've posted it, the Problem was I did this: xml.LoadXml(contentList[0].BodyText); in a cycle, which was obviously overwriting it even when it had to be cancelled. the same code without the cycle works, strange